# Switch between array entries

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing an application which interfaces with an external API. We have five API clients (in order to process more requests - which is allowed under the API T&C) which are stored in an array. We have another array of objects which we perform an action on using `foreach`.

For example:

```
$clients = array(
    array(
        "key" => "somekey",
        "secret" => "somesecret"
    ),
    array(
        "key" => "somekey",
        "secret" => "somesecret"
    ),
    array(
        "key" => "somekey",
        "secret" => "somesecret"
    )
);
```

Next we have an array of objects to be processed:

```
$objects = array(
    array(
        "info" => "someinfo",
        "url" => "someurl",
        "id" => 1234,
        "more" => "more"
    ),
    array(
        "info" => "someinfo",
        "url" => "someurl",
        "id" => 1234,
        "more" => "more"
    ),
    array(
        "info" => "someinfo",
        "url" => "someurl",
        "id" => 1234,
        "more" => "more"
    )
);
```

So to process them with one API key we would do something like:

```
foreach($objects as $object){
     $class->setAPIKey($clients[0]);
     $result = $class->process($object);
}
```

In order to process them with multiple keys we have tried this:

```
$key = 0;
foreach($objects as $object){
    $class->setAPIKey($clients[$key]);
    $result = $class->process($object);
    if($key + 1 == sizeof($clients)){
        $key = 0;
    } else {
        $key++;
    }
}
```

This works, but seems a little inefficient. Is there a quicker/smaller way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
foreach($objects as $key => $object){
     $class->setAPIKey($clients[$key]);
     $result = $class->process($object);
}
```